# Parse Wikipedia dump into plain text where preserving the structure (sections)

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-templates

I have been searching for wikipedia dump parser into customizable xml , basically each article should be parsed into a set of section tags , containing the section plain text of the article. I come up with the following solutions

- [DizzyLogic](https://dizzylogic.com/wikiparser)
- [WikiExtractor](https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor)

The problem with the first one is that it is available only on windows and the second doesn't give the capability of producing the sections in a nested xml scheme . Previous implementations of [mwlib](https://mwlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) seems to provide such capabilities but sadly new versions are not . Is there any wikipedia xml dump parser on linux which can produce customizable xmls ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is doable using jsonwikipedia [1]. which generates a "json dump" out of the Wikipedia XML dump.  more details on jsonwikipedia and other tools in this blog post [2]

[1] - https://github.com/idio/json-wikipedia

[2] - http://engineering.idioplatform.com/2016/02/18/wikipedia-toolkit.html